# LND make install Error 127

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, linux

I try to install LND like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd
cd lnd
sudo make install
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: go: not found
make: *** [Makefile:112: install] Error 127
```

Go is installed. Go version:

```
go version go 1.20.2 linux/arm
```

.profile PATH is exported:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

.bashrc contains:

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell cannot find the `go` binary in the `PATH` thats because when you use `sudo` the command is run in a new environment and some environment variable can not be there like `PATH` Here is how to fix that:

open a terminal then open the sudo configuration file in a text editor with `sudo visudo` then add `:/usr/local/go/bin` at the end of `Defaults` `secure_path=`

If you still have problem try to reinstall your `go`

Comment: The -E flag was not the solution but got me on the right track. Change your answer to something like this and I can mark it as correct answered. 
open sudo config with sudo visudo and add :/usr/local/go/bin at the end of Defaults secure_path =

Comment: okay, thats a working solution :)